# How to remove the row by Index

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm building a Java desktop application that use JTable and DefaultTableModel.

Now, I have implemented a KeyEventListener of this table. So if I try to click on CANC button of my keyBoard, I want to remove the selected row. But there is this strange behavior.

This is my first table:

[image]

Now I select the penultimate row then I press the CANCEL button of my keyboard. This is the result

[image]

As you can see, delete the penultimate ROW but not refresh the JTable.

This is the evetListener:

```
public class KeyListenerTableFattura extends KeyAdapter {
        private JTable table2;
        private MyTableModelFatturaManuale tableModel;

        public KeyListenerTableFattura(JTable table2) {
            this.table2 = table2;
            this.tableModel = (MyTableModelFatturaManuale)table2.getModel();
        }

        public void keyReleased (KeyEvent ke) {
            if (table2.getSelectedColumn() == 0) {
                //tasto canc
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == 127) {
                    try{
                        int riga= table.getSelectedRow();
                        ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
                        selectionModel.setSelectionInterval(0,0);
                        tableModel.rimuoviSpesa(riga);      

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        log.logStackTrace(e);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void printIt(String title, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

        }

    }
```

This is the TableModel

```
package com.mcsolution.commercialista.table.tableModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.mcsolution.commercialista.beans.FatturaRighe;
import com.mcsolution.common.supporto.VisualMessage;



public class MyTableModelFatturaManuale extends defaultTableModel{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3163597322286902696L;
    public List<FatturaRighe> v = new ArrayList<FatturaRighe>();
    public static String[] ColName = {"Descrizione","Importo"};
    private Double percEnpaCL=0.0,percIva=0.0,perRitenuta=0.0;
    private Double imponibileIva =0.0,empaCL=0.0,iva=0.0,ritenutaAcconto=0.0,lordo=0.0,netto=0.0,
            totale=0.0;

    private int rigaParziale =7;
    private int rigaEnpaCl =6;
    private int rigaImponibileIva =5;
    private int rigaIva =4;
    private int rigaRitenuta =3;
    private int rigaTotaleLordo =2;
    private int rigaNetto =1;
    private int rigaTotale =0;
    public MyTableModelFatturaManuale() {
        super(ColName,0);   
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void inserisciRigheFisse(){
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("PARZIALE", this.getRowCount()-1, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0,00", this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("ENPACL 0 %", this.getRowCount()-1, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0,00", this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("IMPONIBILE I.V.A.", this.getRowCount()-1, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0,00", this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("I.V.A. 0 %", this.getRowCount()-1, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0,00", this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("RIT.ACCONTO 0 %", this.getRowCount()-1, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0,00", this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("TOTALE LORDO", this.getRowCount()-1, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0,00", this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("NETTO", this.getRowCount()-1, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0,00", this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("TOTALE", this.getRowCount()-1, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0,00", this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
    }

    public void settaSpesa(FatturaRighe f){
        this.v.add(f);
        int riga = this.getRowCount()-1;
        this.insertRow(riga, new Vector());
        super.setValueAt(f.getDescrizione(), riga, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0.00", riga, 1);
    }

    private Integer getCountSpeseTaxFree(){
        int cont=0;
        for (FatturaRighe object : this.v) {
            if(!object.getSoggettoIVA())
                cont++;
        }
        return cont;
    }


    public void settaEnpaCl(Double enpa){
        this.percEnpaCL=enpa;
        //modifico l'enpaCL
        super.setValueAt("ENPACL "+this.percEnpaCL+" %", this.getRowCount()-1-rigaEnpaCl-getCountSpeseTaxFree(), 0);
        calcolaTotale();
    }

    public void settaIva(Double iva){
        this.percIva=iva;
        //modifico l'enpaCL
        super.setValueAt("I.V.A. "+this.percIva+" %", this.getRowCount()-1-rigaIva-getCountSpeseTaxFree(), 0);
        calcolaTotale();
    }

    public void settaRitenuta(Double ritenuta){
        this.perRitenuta=ritenuta;
        //modifico l'enpaCL
        super.setValueAt("RIT.ACCONTO "+this.perRitenuta+" %", this.getRowCount()-1-rigaIva-getCountSpeseTaxFree(), 0);
        calcolaTotale();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //verifico quante solo le righe della tabella
        int righeEsentiIva = getCountSpeseTaxFree();
        int righeIva = this.v.size() - righeEsentiIva;
        //se è l'ultima riga non si modifica
        if(rowIndex == this.getRowCount()-1) //metto il meno uno perchè a contare si paprte dallo 0
            return false;
        else if(rowIndex < righeIva)
            return true;
        else if(rowIndex >= righeIva+7 && rowIndex < this.getRowCount())
            return true;
        return false;

    }
    public void inserisciRiga(){
        FatturaRighe f = new FatturaRighe();
        f.setImporto(0.00);
        f.setSoggettoIVA(true);
        this.v.add(0,f);
        this.insertRow(0, new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("", 0, 0);
        super.setValueAt("0.00", 0, 1);
    }

    public void rimuoviRiga(){
        //conto il numero di righe presenti
        int righeEsistenti = this.v.size() - getCountSpeseTaxFree();
        if(righeEsistenti >0){
            this.v.remove(0);
            this.removeRow(0);
            calcolaTotale();    
        }
    }

    public void rimuoviSpesa(int nRiga){
        //conto il numero di righe presenti
        int righeIvaEsente = getCountSpeseTaxFree();
        if(righeIvaEsente<=0)
            return;
        this.removeRow(nRiga);
        //mi vado a calcolare nella lista dove si trova questa riga
        int nPosizioneInLista = nRiga - 7;
        this.v.remove(nPosizioneInLista);
        calcolaTotale();    
    }


    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        try{
            //verifico se la riga è già esistente oppure va modificata
            //altero il valore di rowIndex perchè ci sono le 6 righe fisse
            int rigaIniziale = rowIndex;
            if(rowIndex >7)
                rowIndex = rowIndex-7;
            FatturaRighe f = rowIndex< this.v.size() ? this.v.get(rowIndex) : null;
            if(f==null){
                f = new FatturaRighe();
                f.setSoggettoIVA(true);
                //mi calcolo quante spese ci sono
                int spese = getCountSpeseTaxFree();
                if(spese>0){
                    this.v.add(rowIndex-spese,f);
                }else
                    this.v.add(f);
            }
            if(columnIndex==0){
                //descrizion
                f.setDescrizione(aValue.toString());
            }else if(columnIndex==1){
                //importo
                try{
                    Double importo = Double.parseDouble(aValue.toString());
                    f.setImporto(importo);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    VisualMessage.getErrore();
                }               
            }

            super.setValueAt(f.getDescrizione(), rigaIniziale>7 ? rigaIniziale : rowIndex, 0);
            super.setValueAt(f.getImporto(), rigaIniziale>7 ? rigaIniziale : rowIndex, 1);

            calcolaTotale();
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.logStackTrace(e);
        }
    }

    public void calcolaTotale(){
        try{
            Double parziale=0.0;
            Double totaleSpese=0.0;
            for (FatturaRighe fattura : this.v) {
                if(fattura.getSoggettoIVA()==true){
                    parziale += fattura.getImporto()!=null ? fattura.getImporto() : 0.00;
                }else
                    totaleSpese += fattura.getImporto()!=null ? fattura.getImporto() : 0.00;
            }
            empaCL=parziale*this.percEnpaCL/100;
            imponibileIva = parziale + empaCL;
            iva = imponibileIva*percIva/100;
            ritenutaAcconto= parziale*perRitenuta/100;
            lordo = imponibileIva+iva;
            netto = lordo-ritenutaAcconto;
            totale = netto+ totaleSpese;
            int righeSenzaTasse = getCountSpeseTaxFree();
            //io so che l'ultima riga conterrà sempre il parziale
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(parziale), this.getRowCount()-1-rigaParziale-righeSenzaTasse, 1);
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(empaCL), this.getRowCount()-1-rigaEnpaCl-righeSenzaTasse, 1);
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(imponibileIva), this.getRowCount()-1-rigaImponibileIva-righeSenzaTasse, 1);
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(iva), this.getRowCount()-1-rigaIva-righeSenzaTasse, 1);
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(ritenutaAcconto), this.getRowCount()-1-rigaRitenuta-righeSenzaTasse, 1);
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(lordo), this.getRowCount()-1-rigaTotaleLordo-righeSenzaTasse, 1);
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(netto), this.getRowCount()-1-rigaNetto-righeSenzaTasse, 1);
            //super.setValueAt("TOTALE", this.getRowCount()-1-rigaTotale, 0);
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(totale), this.getRowCount()-1-rigaTotale, 1);
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.logStackTrace(e);
            VisualMessage.getErrore();
        }

    }



    public Class<Float> getColumnClass(Float columnIndex) {
        return Float.class;    // Le due colonne sono numeri interi
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void stampaTabella(List<FatturaRighe> v){
        int i=0;
        this.v=v;
        Double totale=0.0;
//      for(Iterator<FatturaText> it=v.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
//          FatturaText fattura =it.next();
//          this.addRow(new Vector());
//          super.setValueAt(fattura.getCodFattura(), i,0);
//          super.setValueAt(fattura.getDataFormattata(), i,1);
//          if(fattura.getCliente()!=null)
//              super.setValueAt(fattura.getCliente().getRagioneSociale(), i,2);
//          
//          super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(fattura.getTotale())+" €", i, 3);
//          totale+=fattura.getTotale();
//          i++;
//      }
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt("TOTALE", i, 0);
        super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(totale)+" €", i, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need more help then post a proper [mcve]. We are not interested in your application only code that demonstrates the problem. So you just need to create a frame with a JTable using the DefaultTableModel. There is no need for a custom TableModel to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I have implemented a KeyEventListener of this table. So if I try to click on CANC button of my keyBoard, I want to remove the selected row

What do a `KeyListener` and "clicking" on a button have to do with one another?

When you click on a button you should be adding an `ActionListener` to the button to handle an event.

> if (ke.getKeyCode() == 127)

First of all you shouldn't be using a KeyListener to listen for KeyEvents. If you do use a listener then don't use magic numbers, nobody knows what "127" is. Instead use the variables defined in the `KeyEvent` API. For example: KeyEvent.VK_A.

In any case you problem is that the `JTable` will place a cell in editing mode when any KeyEvent is received.

If you need to do special processing on a special KeyStroke then you should be using `Key Bindings`. Then the KeyStroke is handle by the binding and the editor will not be invoked.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information and examples. Note you will use the `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT InputMap` when setting up the key binding.

Comment: thanks for your response, but can you give me an exaple to use this ?

Comment: @bircastri, the tutorial has example code. This [link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) attempts to simply the basic code needed to create a binding. All you need to do is write the Action. The forum is also full of examples that use Key Bindings. If you need more help, then post a proper [mcve] that shows what you have tried. The entire class would be about 20 lines of code. A few lines to create the frame, another couple to create a table and a few more for the key bindings. The point of the `MCVE` is to learn a concept, then you apply the concept to your code.